# format decimal to store 6 decimals

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I'm using decimals to store longitute and latitude. Without any config in asp.net mvc4 form I'm getting in mssql db value like this (with losing last digit)

> 48.42920

and I should save this as

```
48.429201
```

Question is how to format decimal to meet this requirement?

THanks

Comment: In your database design, are the fields set as decimal(N,6). 6 is the precision.

Comment: what is the datatype in your database for Latitude and Longitude there should be a datatype for this I remember doing something like this when doing GPS Maps coding back in 2010 also are you doing any Casting in code..remember never use `.ConvertToDecimal` always cast `(decimal)`so you don't lose any precession

Comment: @user1765862 Post that as an answer of the problem/solution and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Inside `mssql field` should be set as `decimal(N,6).` 
6 is the precision